# How to find out whether the check box is checked or not checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below code in my jsp.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="transport" id="bike" value="Bike"> I have a bike
<input type="checkbox" name="transport" id="car" value="Car"> I have a car
<input type="checkbox" name="transport" id="cycle" value="cycle"> I have a cycle
```

using jQuery I have to get all values whose check box is checked. How can I get the values whose check box is checked?

Comment: There are many ways, try to google on it.

Comment: Please look on to this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/901712/3213745

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with jQuery, but try this:

```
var values = [];
$('input[name="transport"]').each(function () {
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        values.push( $(this).attr('value') );
    }
});

alert(values);
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('value')` can simply be `$(this).val()` or `this.value`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#bike').is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':checkbox[name=transport]:checked').each(function (i, ele) {
    var value = $(ele).val();
    console.log(value); 
});
```

Comment: this will result only with one value (the last selected checkbox)

Comment: not if he do something with the value inside the .each()